# Unable to pass value using ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm completely new to ajax. I want to pass my html form value to php and then get the output from that php page back in the html page

Ajax code

```
 $("#submit1").click(function(){
 var formData = $("#add-cart-form").serialize();

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {
        'total_load' : $('#total_load').val(),
        'hours' : $('#hours').val(),
    },
     success: function (data) {
       alert(data)
     },
  });
 var result = $.parseJSON(output);
 alert(result[0]);
});
```

Relevant php code

```
$connected_load = $_POST['total_load'];  $no_of_hours = $_POST['hours'];


 echo json_encode(array(
     $connected_load, 
     $selected_inverter["model"], 
     $selected_inverter["voltage"], 
     $selected_inverter["type"],
     $no_of_hours,$selected_battery));
```

Comment: And what? Waht errors do you encounter? What is all this `$connected_load`, `$selected_inverter`?

Comment: These are the variables that need to be passed back to my html page
The values aren't going to the php file hence no output

Comment: Without seeing at least how you receive values there's nothing can be said. Check developer's console.

Comment: I've added the input part too. Please see it now

Comment: I've also checked console. Nothing is being displayed over there on running the code.

Comment: Check developer's console to see raw `PHP` response. Are you sure that you are using the right URL? In the `success` callback you use the `AJAX` response as `data` variable, but after that point, i can only see `$.parseJSON(output)`... Where did `output` came from? Could you please be more cleaner asking your question?

Comment: The output is from the php file that i've echoed there.The url is correct.

Comment: [Firefox dev console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) and [chrome dev console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/console/console-ui?hl=en) use the dev console to look at network traffic on the page and than filter by xhr to see the ajax requests. You can see what data exactly you sent and what exactly the server responded with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, code has some inaccuracies.
First of all, you're writing:

```
var formData = $("#add-cart-form").serialize();
```

...but you're not sending `formData` via $.ajax. Instead, you're sending other post data, specifically

```
{ 'total_load' : $('#total_load').val(), 'hours' : $('#hours').val(),}
```

...and there is an error inside this object, you have a comma just before the closing curly brace.

Anyway, this is the right way to do it (js)

```
$("#submit1").click(function(event){
    // perhaps formData form embrace "total_load" and "hours" ?
    var formData = $("#add-cart-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        cache: false, // optional
        async: true, // optional, defaults to true. False value will make ajax synchronous, hanging the browser.
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function(d){ // trying to simplify comprehension of the console.log output, below...
        console.log(d.d_connected_load);
        console.log(d.d_model);
        console.log(d.d_voltage);
        console.log(d.d_type);
        console.log(d.d_no_of_hours);
        console.log(d.d_selected_battery);
    }).fail(function(j,s,e){
        console.warn(j.responseText);
    });

});
```

and, PHP side:

```
<?php
    $connected_load = $_POST['total_load'];
    $no_of_hours = $_POST['hours'];

    # stuffs here for sanitizing $_POST and working on $selected_inverter["model"], $selected_inverter["voltage"], $selected_inverter["type"], $selected_battery

 echo json_encode(
    array(
        "d_connected_load" => $connected_load, 
        "d_model" => $selected_inverter["model"], 
        "d_voltage" => $selected_inverter["voltage"], 
        "d_type" => $selected_inverter["type"],
        "d_no_of_hours" => $no_of_hours,
        "d_selected_battery" => $selected_battery
        )
    );
```

You do not need to parse JSON. jQuery will do it for you when you make an ajax call specifying `dataType:'json'` in the ajaxcall options (and, obviously, the json echoed from php must be well-formed).

Note, in addition, the way the ajax call is written. In latest releases of jQuery the best is to use `.done()` and `.fail()` promise methods instead of `success` and `fail`. -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**UPDATE:** STEP BY STEP EXAMPLE:

I'll try to make it more understandable.
Initial steps:

- create a file named form.php;
- create a file named ajax_test.php;
- create a file named test.js;

...in the same directory.

```
====== FILE FORM.PHP ======
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="add-cart-form" method="post">
        <p>TOTAL LOAD: <input type="text" value="total load" name="total_load" /></p>
        <p>TOTAL LOAD: <input type="text" value="hours!" name="hours" /></p>
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" id="submit1">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</html>


====== FILE AJAX_TEST.PHP ======
<?php
    $connected_load = $_POST['total_load'];
    $no_of_hours = $_POST['hours'];

    # stuffs here for sanitizing $_POST and working on $selected_inverter["model"], $selected_inverter["voltage"], $selected_inverter["type"], $selected_battery

 echo json_encode(
    array(
        "d_connected_load" => $connected_load, 
        "d_model" => $selected_inverter["model"], 
        "d_voltage" => $selected_inverter["voltage"], 
        "d_type" => $selected_inverter["type"],
        "d_no_of_hours" => $no_of_hours,
        "d_selected_battery" => $selected_battery
        )
    );


====== FILE TEST.JS ======

$("#submit1").click(function(event){
   // perhaps formData form embrace "total_load" and "hours" ?
    var formData = $("#add-cart-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_test.php',
        cache: false, // optional
        async: true, // optional, defaults to true. False value will make ajax synchronous, hanging the browser.
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function(d){ // trying to simplify comprehension of the console.log output, below...
        console.log(d.d_connected_load);
        console.log(d.d_model);
        console.log(d.d_voltage);
        console.log(d.d_type);
        console.log(d.d_no_of_hours);
        console.log(d.d_selected_battery);
    }).fail(function(j,s,e){
        console.warn(j.responseText);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Thanx for the help
I tried this code but it isn't giving any output in console.
I added an alert string inside .done() and that also didn't give any result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `output` variable is not defined at this point. Try to parse response in the callback success function:

```
success: function (data) {
     var result = $.parseJSON(data);
     console.log(result[0]);
}
```

Comment: Tried this still there was no output in console.
The values are going to test.php
But the values are not returning back to my html page.